# Cannot make cross origin request between local ASP.NET Core MVC services

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two applications running locally. one is a web service at `https://localhost:44365`, the other is a web application at `https://localhost:44360`. The web application needs to access the web service.

The web service is set up with a cors policy that should allow this:

```
// For running on local pc
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
    });
    ...
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
    app.useMvc();
    ...
}
```

When I run both applications and hit the web application in my browser, I get cross origin errors:

> Failed to load https://localhost:44365/api/users/current/avatarText: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost:44360' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

The headers in from the service (at 44365) were:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: content-type
access-control-allow-origin: https://localhost:44360
```

Oddly, I also show a 500 server error in the method in question. Although when the application (44360) calls it, I am able to step through the method (in 44365) and there is no 500 within that method. I can call it successfully when the call is not cross origin.

Comment: It's the 500 you want to investigate, rather than the CORS side of this. My guess is there's something different about how you're making the request from whatever's running on https://localhost:44360 that's causing something in your pipeline to blow up.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [AllowAllOrigins](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.cors.infrastructure.corspolicybuilder.allowanyorigin)

```
options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
    builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
    });
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1#set-the-allowed-origins

> Consider carefully before allowing requests from any origin. Allowing requests from any origin means that any website can make cross-origin requests to your app.
>
> This setting affects [preflight requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1#preflight-requests) and the
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin header (described later in this topic).

Comment: ok then I think you are missing something else, can you share some more code? show how you are calling this code?